# Django/DRF Decimal Field filter not working

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Here is my models field:

```
latitude = models.DecimalField(
    _('latitude'), max_digits=20, decimal_places=17,
    blank=True, null=True)
```

Now in django shell

```
In [34]: GeoLocation.objects.first().latitude
Out[34]: Decimal('28.64871730000000000')


In [35]: Decimal('28.64871730000000000')
...: 
Out[35]: Decimal('28.64871730000000000')
```

Above line **[Out]34** and **[Out]35** is same 
But the filter is not working.

```
In [36]: 
GeoLocation.objects.filter(latitude=Decimal(28.64871730000000000))
Out[36]: <QuerySet []>

In [37]: 
GeoLocation.objects.filter(latitude=Decimal('28.64871730000000000'))
Out[37]: <QuerySet []>



In [53]: s = GeoLocation.objects.first().latitude

In [54]: GeoLocation.objects.filter(latitude=s)
Out[54]: <QuerySet []>
```

Comment: Tested with SQLite and it works. Could you add more details about your database settings? Another thing that might be helpful would be the output of `str(GeoLocation.objects.filter(latitude=Decimal('28.64871730000000000')).query)`

Comment: DATABASES = {
    
        'default': dj_database_url.config(
            default='sqlite:///' + project_dir('res_api_demo.sqlite')
        )
    }                                                                                                                 
 'SELECT "api_geolocation"."id", "api_geolocation"."created", "api_geolocation"."_data", "api_geolocation"."formatted_address", "api_geolocation"."latitude", "api_geolocation"."longitude" FROM "api_geolocation" WHERE "api_geolocation"."latitude" = 28.64871730000000000'

Comment: What database backend are you using? Also check that you have applied all migrations

Comment: Using SQLITE, and Yes migration also done